# Oracle error creating IDENTITY column

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a `CREATE TABLE` statement which works fine.

However, when the following is added (as the first column in the table):

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
    id NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
```

This error is thrown:

```
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-02000: missing ( keyword
02000. 00000 -  "missing %s keyword"
```

What is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: That syntax isn't supported until Oracle 12c.

Comment: What is wrong? - Wrong Oracle version: check the manual for Oracle 11: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#CEGEDHJE there is no `identity` in there